# Find the lowest PHP array value (specific) and return lowest key

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, `$prices`, which looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [regprice] => 25.00
            [saleprice] => 17.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [regprice] => 
            [saleprice] => 19.00
        )

)
```

When using `$lowest_index = array_keys($prices, min($prices));`, `$lowest_index` returns `1`, because for that index, the value `[regprice]` is not set.

I would like to get the index of the array where `[saleprice]` is the lowest. In my case, that would return `0`.

Comment: Is there always a `saleprice`?

Comment: @Nick Thanks for your comment. Yes, `saleprice` is always filled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is always a value in `saleprice`, you can adapt your code using [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to look at only the `saleprice` values:

```
$lowest_index = array_keys(array_column($prices, 'saleprice'), min(array_column($prices, 'saleprice')));
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Mf3kj)